# Flask - Multiprocessing issue

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

Below is my flask, multiprocessing code. If I execute I'm getting print of "Opened database successfully" twice. And if I make debug = True, I'm getting it thrice. Please help me understand where I'm going wrong.

```
from flask import Flask
from multiprocessing import Manager
import sqlite3 as sql


app = Flask(__name__)


db_path = "D:/abc.db"

# reading the database
conn = sql.connect(db_path)
print ("Opened database successfully")
  

@app.route('/')
def func():
    print("Hello")    
    ## Instantiating Managers
    manager = Manager()
    return_list1 = manager.list()
    return_list2 = manager.list()
    
   
    return {}


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug = False, port=5003)
```

Comment: all of the code that is not inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` will be run twice (you don't need to put function and class definitions there as they are not called by being defined)

Comment: 1. Why will it be run twice? Any idea?
2. My motivation to put code there was to make the variables which are not serializable , available to all service methods. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: it won't necessarily be run twice, it will be run as many times as new processes are started. why? because each new process pretty much just runs the same file probably because you set it to have a target but that target has to be defined in that same file, so it reruns the entire code and uses that name. Also, memory is not shared among processes so you can't do that, put everything that is directly executed under the `if name == main`, for sharing data you need to use the managers (there was sth else too) and pass that as the argument. And why exactly you want to use the manager anyways?

Answer (score 0):

I will infer that you are running under Windows or some platform that uses OS *spawn* to create new processes based on the behavior.

In calling `Manager()`, two things happen:

1. A new instance of `multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager` is created and
2. Method `start` is called on this instance.

Calling `start` results in a new process being started. Method invocations on the managed lists that you have created are actually invocations on proxy objects. The actual list objects reside in the address space of this new `SyncManager` process. And as you probably know, when *spawn* is used to create new processes, any code in the source program at global scope gets re-executed to initialize the new process. However, `__name__` will not be '__main__' for the new process, so any code that you do not want executed by this initialization because it is either harmful or just plain unnecessary should be placed within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

So you are opening your SQL connection once when your program is loaded and then again for every time your endpoint is invoked (or any endpoint in the same source). Also, you are needlessly creating too many `SyncManager` instances:

```py
from flask import Flask
import sqlite3 as sql


app = Flask(__name__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Manager
    # reading the database
    db_path = "D:/abc.db"
    conn = sql.connect(db_path)
    print ("Opened database successfully")
    manager = Manager()
  

@app.route('/')
def func():
    print("Hello")    
    ## Instantiating Managers
    return_list1 = manager.list()
    return_list2 = manager.list()
    
   
    return {}


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug = False, port=5003)
```